WebStorm. No color in code configuration on Linux
WebStorm app doesn't have color in code configuration. Although everything is indicated and shown correctly in the settings. How to fix this problem?
WebStorm 2024.2 running on Linux Mint 22.
On a Windows system, the same version of the WebStorm application works well. The settings are also the same. I assume that there may be a problem in Linux. I changed themes, removed and installed plugins. Nothing helped.
I have attached screenshots of what it looks like and a screenshot of the settings.





Try disabling all custom (not bundled by default) plugins, restart the IDE and see if it makes any difference. It could be one of them that interferes. 2) What the IDE thinks about such a file? Focus is in the Project view panel, invoke "View | Quick Documentation" on it and share the screenshot. 3) There is a chance that there is something wrong with the File Types. Please show what File Types have *.tsx and .ts patterns 4) Could also be that Texmate bundle is the one that provides colors here and not the IDEs own functionality...

